# PyQt4 Subwindow in MDI. Check which subwindow is active

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

in the following executable code you can create more subwindow. But, when I switch from one subwindow to the other, I want the progrm detect which subwindow is current active. Image, we have opend two subwindow. One subwindow we call it A and the other subwindow we call it B. Both of them are already open. Subwindow A ist active, now I switch to Subwindow B. How can the class `Custom_Window()` tell me "I am here and I am currently active"?.

**UPDATE**

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Custom_Window(QWidget) :  
   def __init__(self, parent = None) :
      super(Custom_Window, self) .__init__(parent)

      # print here in this class, that itself is currently active,
      # because this window is a subwindow, so its inherits from class
      # QMdiSubWindow(). I want this subwindow itself tell me
      # whether its activated or not. BUT I don't know how to
      # solve this idea.

   def changeEvent(self, event):

      print "event", event
      print "type", type(self.parent())
      print "Status", self.parent().isActiveWindow()

      if event.type() == QEvent.WindowActivate:
         if self.parent().isActiveWindow():
            print "is currently active."
         else: print "I am passive"

class MainWindow(QMainWindow) :
   count = 0

   def __init__(self, parent = None) :
      super(MainWindow, self) .__init__(parent)
      self.mdi = QMdiArea()
      self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
      bar = self.menuBar()

      file = bar.addMenu("File")
      file.addAction("New")
      file.addAction("cascade")
      file.addAction("Tiled")
      file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)
      self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

   def windowaction(self, q) :
       custom_window = Custom_Window()
       print "triggered"

       if q.text() == "New" :
           MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count+1
           sub = QMdiSubWindow()
           sub.setWidget(Custom_Window() )
           sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow"+str(MainWindow.count) )
           self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
           sub.show()

       if q.text() == "cascade" :
           self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()

       if q.text() == "Tiled" :
           self.mdi.tileSubWindows()

def main() :
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = MainWindow()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_() )

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Did you look at the Qt docs? There are several very obvious APIs for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Hey  ekhumoro, I didn't find something.

Comment: So you don't see anything [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#public-functions), or [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#public-functions)? If those don't do what you want, you need to explain much more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the code. Take a look at the `Custom_Window()`-class. There you will find my comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why that documentation I linked to doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know how.

Comment: I have edited my code again. Well I have overwritten the `changeEvent()`-method, but I doesn't work. Both subwindows say they are activated and return True. This is false. When one subwindow is activated, then the other subwindow can't return True at the same time, that says its also activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt docs for [QMdiArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#public-functions) show you which APIs to use. There is a [subWindowActivated](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#subWindowActivated) signal that is designed for this purpose, so just connect a slot to it:

```
class Custom_Window(QWidget) :

    def handleActivationChange(self, subwindow):
        if subwindow is self.parent():
            print 'activated:', self
        else:
            print 'deactivated:', self

...

       self.mdi.subWindowActivated.connect(
          sub.widget().handleActivationChange)
```